# SwiftUI: toggle buttons state inside List

Tags: swiftui, binding, combine

I try to implement a simple player app with a tracks list where each row has a play button, and if I press Play for one track, current playing track (if any) should stop playing (in this case Play button should change icon). Here I got some questions - how do I identify current playing track (where Play button is in playing mode), how can I reset it to initial state so that only one track plays at a time.

In this example multiple buttons can be switched to playing state, not exclusively one as desired

```
import SwiftUI

class Audio: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    @Published var isPlaying = false {
        didSet {
            print(isPlaying)
        }
    }
    
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

class AudiosFetcher: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var audios = [Audio]()
    
    func fetchAudios() {
        audios = [
            Audio(title: "track 1"),
            Audio(title: "track 2"),
            Audio(title: "track 3")
        ]
    }
    
}

struct ListRow: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var audio: Audio
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                audio.isPlaying.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: audio.isPlaying ? "pause.circle" : "play.circle")
            }
            .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            .font(.largeTitle)
            
            Text(audio.title)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var audiosFetcher = AudiosFetcher()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(audiosFetcher.audios, id: \.id) { audio in
            ListRow(audio: audio)
        }.onAppear {
            audiosFetcher.fetchAudios()
        }
    }
}
```

**Update: solution**

Thanks to @Yrb's answer, we can do it like this. Maybe `AudiosFetcher` is not the best place to hold current playing audio, but it works and can be extracted to a separate entity if needed

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // The intialization of the ObservableObject should be a @StateObject,
    // not an @ObservedObject.
    @StateObject var audiosFetcher = AudiosFetcher()
    
    var body: some View {
        List($audiosFetcher.audios) { audio in
            ListRow(audiosFetcher: audiosFetcher, audio: audio)
        }
        .onAppear {
            audiosFetcher.fetchAudios()
        }
    }
}

struct ListRow: View {
    
    @StateObject var audiosFetcher: AudiosFetcher
    @Binding var audio: Audio
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                audiosFetcher.playingAudio = (audiosFetcher.playingAudio == audio ? nil : audio)
            }) {
                Image(systemName: audiosFetcher.playingAudio == audio ? "pause.circle" : "play.circle")
            }
            .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            .font(.largeTitle)
            
            Text(audio.title)
        }
    }
}

struct Audio: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

class AudiosFetcher: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var audios = [Audio]()
    @Published var playingAudio: Audio?
    
    func fetchAudios() {
        audios = [
            Audio(title: "track 1"),
            Audio(title: "track 2"),
            Audio(title: "track 3")
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked a few things. First of all, since you only want one audio, at most, playing I pulled the playing state out of the data model `Audio`. I also turned it into a struct, as that is the preferred choice for SwiftUI. I moved the playing state into the view model. In order to simplify the code, I actually removed `ListRow`, though you could inject the view model into `ListRow`. This gives you your source of truth for which audio is playing. It will be `nil` if no audio is playing. The controls are keyed off of this value:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // The intialization of the ObservableObject should be a @StateObject,
    // not an @ObservedObject.
    @StateObject var audiosFetcher = AudiosFetcher()
    
    var body: some View {
        List($audiosFetcher.audios) { $audio in
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    audiosFetcher.isPlaying = (audiosFetcher.isPlaying == audio ? nil : audio)
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: audiosFetcher.isPlaying == audio ? "pause.circle" : "play.circle")
                }
                .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                .font(.largeTitle)
                
                Text(audio.title)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            audiosFetcher.fetchAudios()
        }
    }
}

struct Audio: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

class AudiosFetcher: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var audios = [Audio]()
    @Published var isPlaying: Audio?
    
    func fetchAudios() {
        audios = [
            Audio(title: "track 1"),
            Audio(title: "track 2"),
            Audio(title: "track 3")
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this to reset all audios initial state, and just play one track at a time:

```
class Audio: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    @Published var isPlaying = false {
        didSet {
            print(title + " isPlaying: \(isPlaying)")
        }
    }
    
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

class AudiosFetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var audios = [Audio]()
    
    func fetchAudios() {
        audios = [
            Audio(title: "track 1"),
            Audio(title: "track 2"),
            Audio(title: "track 3")
        ]
    }
    
    // -- here
    func toggleAudio(_ audio: Audio) {
       let inState = audio.isPlaying
       audios.forEach{ $0.isPlaying = false} // <-- turn all off
       audio.isPlaying = !inState  // <-- only toggle this one
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var audiosFetcher = AudiosFetcher() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        List(audiosFetcher.audios, id: \.id) { audio in
            ListRow(audio: audio)
        }.onAppear {
            audiosFetcher.fetchAudios()
        }
        .environmentObject(audiosFetcher) // <-- here
    }
}

struct ListRow: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var audiosFetcher: AudiosFetcher // <-- here
    @ObservedObject var audio: Audio
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                audiosFetcher.toggleAudio(audio) // <-- here
            }) {
                Image(systemName: audio.isPlaying ? "pause.circle" : "play.circle")
            }
            .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            .font(.largeTitle)
            Text(audio.title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this working solution but I'd better avoid using `EnvironmentObject`, see answer by @Yrb